# php multi dimension array select box mysql insert

Tags: php

i have this html code:

```
<select id="users_list" data-placeholder="Choose a user..." multiple name="users_list[]">

        <?php while($users = mysql_fetch_array($all_users)){ ?>

                        <option value='<?php echo serialize(array($users['id_user'], $users['name'], $users['image_url'])); ?>' <?php if($users['id_user'] == $_SESSION['user_id']) echo "disabled"; ?>><?php echo $users['name']; ?></option>

        <?php } ?>

</select>
```

how can i insert values into mysql db ?
To be clear i wrote this php code:

```
$users_list = $_POST['users_list'];
foreach($users_list as $user)
{
    $user = unserialize($user);
    foreach($user as $info){
    }
        $query = "INSERT INTO messages (from_user, to_user, text, sender_name, sender_image, recipant_name, recipant_image, date) VALUES ('$uid', '$user', '$message', '$uname', '$uimage', '$time')";
    $insert = mysql_query($query);
    $mid = mysql_insert_id();
    update_user_notf($user, $uid, $uname, $uimage, $mid, "message");
}
```

That was not right, i need anotherphp code to do the action. Please help.

Comment: I would first check to see if the data was unserialized correctly..

Comment: yes, it's serialized correctly. :)

Comment: `serialize()` returns a binary string that may contain newlines and null bytes, amongst other things. You shouldn't the output in an HTML environment. You'd do better just emitting the user ID into your `<option>` and retrieving the rest of the data server-side.

Comment: Your `INSERT` query specifies eight columns, but provides only six values.

Comment: Yeah Until someone POST's to your page with invalid seriailized data, then this script will fail.